# Does Google Cloud have anything similar to Managed Identity offered by Azure?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, identity, azure-managed-identity, google-cloud-identity

Does Google Cloud have anything similar to the managed identity offered by Azure. Refer the video in below link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview

As I understand Managed Identity eliminates the need for passwords and private keys. Services traditionally use a service account to access resources but that service account uses a password that needs to be stored in a [secrets manager](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager) and periodically auto-rotated. Managed Identity eliminates need of any password.

Answer (score 2):

An Azure System Assigned and User Assigned Identity is similar to a service account assigned to a Compute Engine instance. Neither method require passwords or secrets. Both methods store the authorization tokens in the metadata service.

[Compute Engine: Service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts)

Google Cloud uses the service account identity (OIDC) extensively to authorize services to communicate with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Managed Identities. Like Google Service Account, Azure system assigned managed identity is used to authenticate resources like VM, Key Vault etc. using token/private keys.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/how-managed-identities-work-vm

Comment: The OP asked about a authentication system in GCP - they already seem familiar with Azure. So this does not seem to answer the question.